# How to set typeface for textview programmatically?

Tags: android, textview, typeface

I am using textview in my application. In that I need to change the typeface for the textview programmatically. In a button click function i need to change the textview typeface. If typeface is Normal means i need to convert to Bold(Vice versa). 
     If anybody knows the answer means kindly share with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To make your textView bold programmatically do:

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

To set it back to normal do:

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

To get the current typeface use `getTypeface()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTypeface()

Comment: Hi wolf.... This is working.. how can i get the typeface of textview?

Comment: In a single button click i need to convert the typeface. If normal means bold and bold means normal. Again and again....

Comment: Unfortunately I can't immediately find a way to get whether it is BOLD or NORMAL from the textView object. I suggest you store your own boolean value and update accordingly.

Comment: ok wolf. If u knowing someother solution na, juz share with me.

Comment: After setting italic, It only comes back to normal once, then switching back to italics stays like that (same code).

Answer (score 1):

```
setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style)
```

> Sets the typeface and style in which the text should be displayed, and turns on the fake bold and italic bits in the Paint if the Typeface that you provided does not have all the bits in the style that you specified.

From the Android documentation

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname)
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```